# apache2 mod_remoteip x-forwarded-for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, load-balancing

the setup is as follows:

webserver behind loadbalancer,

loadbalancer sends client-ip via x-forwarded-for,

mod_remoteip is activated on webserver and works as expected.

Configuration: remotip.conf

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

**Problem:**

some (image-)directories are protect via .htaccess-file and mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://([a-z0-9]+\.)*my\.referer\.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  !1.2.3.4 [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [F,NC]
```

Image are only delivered, if referer is correct (my.referer.com) or if remote-ip (1.2.3.4) fits.

Unfortunately this doesn't work with mod_remoteip activated! I tried to use `%{HTTP_FORWARDED}, %{X-Forwarded-For} or %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For}` and not `%{REMOTE_HOST}` but nothing worked. See `Server-Variables` in

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

If I add the local loadbalancer-ip (i.e. 10.0.0.1) via

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  !10.0.0.1 [NC]
```

images are delivered. But now, everybody can see the images...

I hope someone has an idea to fix it!

trace6- apache2 logs:

`[Wed Oct 05 12:03:40.490129 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 13245] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 1.2.3.4:38165] 10.0.0.1 - - ...`

I think mod_rewrite doesn't use the client ip!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **solution**:

use

```
%{REMOTE_ADDR}
```

instead of

```
%{REMOTE_HOST}
```